# How to create an array of nested objects from a csv file in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

This question uses the same data as one of my previous questions, but the question is different. I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
name,score,date
Bob,93,2014
Bob,85,2015
Barry,70,2015
...
```

No two people have the same name, but a person can have multiple entries. How can I create an array within the d3.csv callback function that looks like this?:

```
[{name: "Bob", values: [
   {score: 93, date: 2014},
   {score: 85, date: 2015}]}
 {name: "Barry", values: [
   {score: 70, date: 2015}]},
...
```

Normally I would be able to do this with plain javascript, but accessing property values with `arrayName[objectIndex].objectPropertyName` doesn't work within the d3 callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[d3.nest()](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) function that will convert your csv data into key value pairs. Look at [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y4R3331Wy0d9d4opu8PZ?p=preview) link to view the objects in console. To get minimum maximum data see [this updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y4R3331Wy0d9d4opu8PZ?p=preview).

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
    var updated = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    }).sortKeys(d3.ascending).entries(data);
    console.log(updated);
})
```

Comment: I used d3.nest() prior to your answer. I was trying to get the max score but was having difficulty accessing the values when using d3.max().

Comment: see my updated answer I used min maximum function in d3 to plot the scales.